# 6 of 8 branches missed in Code coverage jUnit

Tags: java, junit

I have written a java method to read a file and return the file content as a string which worked successfully. I then pass the file location as Input and return the file content in String format. Here is the following code snippet :

```
public String readFile(String url) throws <Custom Exception>
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new
            FileReader(url))) //Line A
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new <Custom Exception>;
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

I also need to write jUnit for the following code snippet. I tried my best to cover `Line A` but unfortunately I was not able to get 100% code coverage. Due to some constraints I can't change the code but can change jUnit I wrote following jUnit which gave me 60% of code coverage.

```
FileServiceImpl fileServiceImpl = new FileServiceImpl();

    @Test
    public void readFile_should_read_file() throws <custom_exception>
    {
        String expected = "Test data";
        File file = new File("test.txt");
        try
        {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            writer.write("Test data");
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return;
        }

        String actual = fileServiceImpl.readFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        file.delete();
        assertEquals(expected, actual);

    }

    @Test(expected = <custom_exception>.class)
    public void readFile_should_throw_<custom_exception>() throws <custom_exception>
    {

        File file = new File("test.txt");

        fileServiceImpl.readFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    }
```

Any suggestion how to cover that `Line A` in all possible ways to get 100% coverage? Any help will be great and I would also like to get an explanation so in the future I will be able to solve this issue on my own.

Comment: What lines did it miss?

Comment: mockito and powermockito tag seem irrelevant

Comment: How did you measure coverage? I think it's covered 100%.

Comment: Just for the record: you don't do try/catch in unit tests --- unless you have code that you **want** to throw up. Meaning: your try/catch in the first test is absolutely pointless. If at all you would do a catch and rethrow something like `new IoException("exception while preparing file for test", e)`

Comment: (just guessing) you need to cause an `IOException` to be thrown by `new FileReader(url)` (easiest one: `FileNotFoundException`) - anyhow: tools (including coverage) are only there to help you: just ignore what they say if they are not helping. Also, 100% coverage is most often just dumb. Practices (good ones, too) become a religion if they are followed blindly and you are a coder, not a priest :) BTW: see `java.nio.file.Files.lines()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about line coverage or branch coverage. Almost all static analysis tool like sonar, etc tracks both.

If you are talking about line coverage, i think **Line A is covered.** To check that, there are various plugins available in IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans etc.

In IntelliJ, you can run you test with options "run with coverage" and you can see the coverage inside the IDE.

You can also use build task in maven and gradle,

for gradle, you need to add this in build.gradle file

```
gradle test
```

and for maven, you can use

```
mvn test
```

Comment: I know Line A is covered but we need to cover it with different aspects as well to get 100% coverage